# accessing firestore collections

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm here to firestore, I like the way you can easily integrate the collection into your client application.

At the moment, I'm accessing my collection directly from vue store like this:

```
async createPost({ state, commit }, post) {
  await fb.postsCollection.add({
    createdOn: new Date(),
    content: post.content,
    userId: fb.auth.currentUser.uid,
    userName: state.userProfile.name,
    comments: 0,
    likes: 0
  })
}
```

Is this secure? Because the database is exposed directly to the client-side. As a result, unauthorized data manipulation might occur.  Should I move the database operation into something like an express API, so database operations are done only on the server-side? All the examples and documentation I found have everything on the client-side and the databases are protected with security rules.

Comment: We can't really say if this is "secure" or not, because we don't know the security requirements of your app.  It's up to you to decide on security policies and implement them in your app.  You might want to learn about security rules which can help with this.

Comment: can you indicate your security concerns?

Comment: @Juancki I'm worried that the database is exposed directly to the client-side. As a result, unauthorized data manipulation might occur. But like Doug pointed out, I'm reviewing the security rules, I think I can do something like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules#firestore. – capiono 23 mins ago

Comment: If security concerns you for some specific part of your data you can always create a separate access to that data with Firebase Functions and apply there further controls/permissions for uploading/downloading.